# Winform autoscroll not working

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I have a form containing a user control in which I have a `GroupBox` and in it there is a `TableLayoutPanel` (table1).

One of the rows in this table also contains a `TableLayoutPanel` (table2).

I am adding rows to table2 dynamically when the user clicks a link label, and I need to have a scroll bar but there is no scroll bar.

I tried all combination possible with

```
 AutoScroll = true, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly
```

But nothing helps.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Dock.Fill was the problem...