# Autoscroll not working in tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, autoscroll

As you can see from the below screenshot, my autoscroll isn't working. I have a tablelayoutpanel within the tab, I have autoscroll set to true on both but neither works.

As this question suggested, I tried getting rid of Dock.Fill (my docking is now set to None through the designer), but this didn't work either. [Winform autoscroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073511/winform-autoscroll-not-working)

Any suggestions on what I can do to get it to scroll down when a new question is added?

[image: Autoscroll isn't working!]

I'm trying out the following code in my case statement, when I answer yes for question D it just displays 0,0 as the position of the autoscroll and doesn't move it down.

```
        Case "DY"
            Dim q As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
            For Each q In Questions
                If q.Key = "E" Then
                    For Each c As Control In Appl1HealthQuestions.Controls
                        ShowControls(15, 16, 17, cbo)
                    Next
                    Appl1TabScrollLayout.AutoScroll = True
                    Appl1TabScrollLayout.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Me.AutoScrollPosition.X, Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y - 20)
                    MessageBox.Show(Applicant1Tab.AutoScrollPosition.ToString)
                    MessageBox.Show(Appl1TabScrollLayout.AutoScrollPosition.ToString)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: It's inside a tabpage yes, but not inside a groupbox. I have nested tablelayoutpanels though. The one I'm referencing in my code is the 'main' one, the one that displays the questions and the comboboxes is another tablelayoutpanel within the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this:

```
Case "DY"
        Dim q As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
        For Each q In Questions
            If q.Key = "E" Then
                For Each c As Control In Appl1HealthQuestions.Controls
                    ShowControls(15, 16, 17, cbo)
                Next
                Appl1TabScrollLayout.VerticalScroll.Value = Appl1TabScrollLayout.VerticalScroll.Maximum
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

The VerticalScroll.Maximum moves the scrolling to the bottom of the window which displays the new control, which is what I was after.